# PHP: Empty Values

Tags: php, smarty

I have a drop down menu generated like this:

```
  <select multiple="multiple" name="application_occupation" id="application_occupation" value="{$fields.Occupation}" class="application_occupation">
              <option selected="selected" value="">All categories</option>
                 {foreach from=$mainArray key=topkey item=topitem}
                 {foreach from=$topitem key=key item=item}
                 <option value="{$item.categoryid}">{$item.name}</option>
            {/foreach}
            {/foreach}<!-- Master -->
      </select>
```

This generates a dropdown menu:

In my php code I have `$fields['Occupation'] = CMS::getFormData('Occupation',           false);`

This is returning blank why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this code

```
$fields['Occupation'] = CMS::getFormData('application_occupation[]', false);
```

If you want use multiple select - name must be this application_occupation[]

Comment: That gave me ` ["Occupation"]=> bool(false)`